# Two questions on replacing an overflow drain with non-overflow

Tags: plumbing, bathroom-fixtures

Online advice says that an overflow lavatory sink will drain more slowly if a non-overflow drain is installed. The explanations are unconvincing. What am I missing? How much slower would it be?

Would commonly available non-overflow drains fit? Except for the overflow feature are the two types interchangeable?

Comment: I am guessing you never plug a sink up, turned on the faucet and had to leave for a longer time than expected.

Comment: There's unanimous online advice, and my personal experience, that the overflow can't keep up with moderat water flow into the sink.

Comment: Why would you intentionally bypass an overflow? Do you intend to keep a bucket under the sink all the time, in case of accident?

Comment: Do the "bowl-on-counter" lavatories have an overflow? We have one bathroom lavatory without an overflow. The lavatory is SS and had an external overflow hose connecting to a hole in the front of the lavatory high up. The drain had an annular overlfow section under the drain which I broke in a poorly thought out plumbing "tweak" at 10 pm. Don't think it is much of a risk; we never turn the water on and go away even for a moment.

Comment: @Jim Stewart Many (most?) bowl-on-counter lavatory sinks don't have an overflow.  I'm not worried about the sink, itself, overflowing. There must be a problem with  time to drain (because nothing I read disagrees) but I can't think of how it comes about, knowing what I do about gravity drain systems. There's nothing about sinks and drains themselves that's a problem or they wouldn't be available in 2 choices. It's something between the tail piece and the soil stack - what?

Answer (score 3):

If the sink has an overflow port, it acts as an additional vent and the water flowing down the drain does so faster.
I have witnessed this first hand and panicked when I installed a new sink in a rental property and filled the sink to check for leaks. Upon opening the drain the water ran slowly making me think there was a partial clog in the drain...but NO!  the chrome ring cover for the drain was still wrapped in the plastic covering.  I removed it and the water drained just fine.

If you install a drain without the access for the overflow you lose this additional venting...as well as losing the overflow protection.

Can they be interchanged?  That depends on the sink design. Sometimes the bowl and overflow are too deep for the non overflow drain and there are not enough (or any) threads to tighten the drain to the bowel.

Best bet is to get the proper drain for your type of sink.